# Combination by groups in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

I am new to MATLAB, and currently stuck at this stage of calculation.

I have a matrix as below:

```
A=
9      2835
9      3843
35     6532
35     6172
35     2034
35     2082
49     3273
49     3241
82     3694
82     2819
82     3334
```

I would like to take out all possible combinations in column 2 of matrix A taken 2 at a time according to the group in column 1 of matrix A

In particular, I would like to results as follow:

```
9       2835        2843
35      2034        2082
35      6172        2082
35      6172        2034
35      6532        2082
35      6532        2034
35      6532        6172

...      ...        ...
```

I know we can use function `combnk` to get all combinations, but I do not know how to do it in group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **[`nchoosek`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html)** (*b = nchoosek(n,k) returns the binomial coefficient, defined as n!/((n–k)! k!). This is the number of combinations of n items taken k at a time.*) could lead you to the solution -

```
%// Find unique col-1 and ID them
[unqA,~,id] = unique(A(:,1))

%// Make groupings of A based on IDs
grpA = arrayfun(@(n) A(id==n,:),1:max(id),'Uni',0)

%// Form the pair-combinations within each groups
combs = arrayfun(@(n) nchoosek(grpA{n}(:,2),2),1:numel(grpA),'Uni',0)

%// Append the col-1 numbers with combinations for a cell array as output
outc = arrayfun(@(n) [repmat(unqA(n),[ size(combs{n},1) 1 ]) combs{n}],...
                                                    1:numel(combs),'Uni',0)
%// If you need a numeic array as the final output
out = vertcat(outc{:})
```

Code run -

```
>> A
A =
           9        2835
           9        3843
          35        6532
          35        6172
          35        2034
          35        2082
          49        3273
          49        3241
          82        3694
          82        2819
          82        3334
>> out
out =
           9        2835        3843
          35        6532        6172
          35        6532        2034
          35        6532        2082
          35        6172        2034
          35        6172        2082
          35        2034        2082
          49        3273        3241
          82        3694        2819
          82        3694        3334
          82        2819        3334
```

Comment: Was about to suggest putting `nchoosek` in a loop.  +1... in about 19 hours!  I maxed out my vote count for the day.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! BTW how do you like my face-mask!? ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my life. It works perfectly. Maybe I am so silly to ask, but can you help me understand why'Uni',0 are used in arrayfun?

Comment: @Anna That `'Uni'` is a shorthand for `'UniformOutput'` and AFAIK with the next parameter being zero/false, tells MATLAB to combine the outputs as cells, because in cells you can keep arrays of different sizes. As an example, you can see, when we are using `arrayfun` for forming the groups `grpA`, each group has different sizes with respect to other groups. So, with `UniformOutput` being false, we are letting MATLAB to make those groupings as cells. Look at the [official doc](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) for more info on `UniformOutput`.

Comment: @Divakar very nice. Suits you! Also finally a +1 for you

Comment: @Divakar Much appreciate your help!